# JSON insert checkbox to search result in table

Tags: json, checkbox

I am creating a search module where I can select the names from the result by using checkbox, my only problem is that my checkbox is not appearing on the column where the result is showing. (*see image for reference*)

The check button is supposed to be in the columns where the number 1 is located.
[image]

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {              
$('#searchTable').dataTable( {
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo site_url() ?>/search/get_account",
        "sServerMethod": "GET",
        "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) 
{
    aoData.push( { "name": "txtClient",     "value": "<?php echo $_POST["txtClient"]; ?>" } );

        $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) 
        {
            fnCallback(json) 
        } );
    },
"aoColumns": [  
    { "sTitle": "<input type='checkbox'></input>","mDataProp": null, "sWidth": "20px", "sClass ": "<input type='checkbox' ></input>", "bSortable": false }, //SELECT
    { "sClass": "centerAligned" , "bSortable" : false }, //CLIENT
    { "sClass": "centerAligned" , "bSortable" : false }, //PROD TYPE
    { "sClass": "centerAligned" , "bSortable" : false }, //REF ACCNT NO.
    { "sClass": "centerAligned" , "bSortable" : false }, //VALUE DATE 
    { "sClass": "centerAligned" , "bSortable" : false }, //MATURITY DATE
    { "sClass": "centerAligned" , "bSortable" : false }, //CCY
    { "sClass": "leftAligned"   , "bSortable" : false }, //PRINCIPAL
    { "sClass": "leftAligned"   , "bSortable" : false }, //RATE (%) 
    { "sClass": "leftAligned"   , "bSortable" : false }, //MATURITY AMNT
    ]
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post the code that is parsing JSON and updating the DOM?

Comment: I'm presuming there's more going on here than JSON and checkboxes. Is this also HTML and JavaScript?

Comment: I edited my codes and include the whole script for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing like this:

```
"aoColumns": [  
        { "sTitle": "<input type='checkbox' class = 'chk'></input>","mDataProp": null, "sWidth": "20px", "sClass ": "<input type='checkbox' class = 'chk'></input>", "bSortable": false }, //SELECT
        { "sClass": "centerAligned" , "bSortable" : false }, //CLIENT
        { "sClass": "centerAligned" , "bSortable" : false }, //PROD TYPE
        { "sClass": "centerAligned" , "bSortable" : false }, //REF ACCNT NO.
        { "sClass": "centerAligned" , "bSortable" : false }, //VALUE DATE 
        { "sClass": "centerAligned" , "bSortable" : false }, //MATURITY DATE
        { "sClass": "centerAligned" , "bSortable" : false }, //CCY
        { "sClass": "leftAligned"   , "bSortable" : false }, //PRINCIPAL
        { "sClass": "leftAligned"   , "bSortable" : false }, //RATE (%) 
        { "sClass": "leftAligned"   , "bSortable" : false }, //MATURITY AMNT
        ]
```

And in `document.ready()` try to do something like this:

```
$(".chk").html("<input class='chk' type='checkbox'>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I already have the answer in this question, sorry I thought that my problem is in the view, but it turns out that the problem is in the model so I just add this in my variable.

```
"<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox".$i."' id='checkbox".$i."' value='".$row->print."' />",
```

instead of

```
$row->print,
```